# Bash script execute wget with a variable inside it

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to execute a wget command with a variable inside it but it just ignores it, any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

URL=http:://www.myurl.com

echo $(date) 'Running wget...'
wget -O - -q "$URL/something/something2"
```

Comment: What makes you think it is being ignored? What is happening exactly?

Comment: it just keeps running, the command im running is supposed to create a log file and it doesnt...maybe I should remove the -O -q flags?

Comment: `-O -` will spit the retrieved document to standard output so you should see output if it is getting the page. You could remove `-q` to see if `wget` says anything about what is going on. But this sounds like it might just be taking `wget` a while to connect. How long have you waited?

Comment: aha, now I see the error: `Resolving http (http)... failed: Name or service not known.`
`wget: unable to resolve host address http`
 and it added ftp:// prefix to the real http:// address...

Comment: You have two colons in your URL.

Comment: Is the two colons in `URL=http:://www.myurl.com` a typo?  Also you should set the `URL=` to `URL="http://www.myurl.com"`.  Also use [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) on your scripts.

Comment: wops! probably starting to lose focus for today...thanks alot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Four things:

1. Add quotes around your URL: http:://www.myurl.com ==> "http:://www.myurl.com"
2. Remove the double colon: "http:://www.myurl.com" ==> "http://www.myurl.com"
3. Get rid of the extra flags and hyphen on the wget command: "wget -O - -q "$URL/something/something2"" ==> wget "$URL/something/something2"
4. Add curly braces around your variable: "wget "$URL/something/something2"" ==> "wget "${URL}/something/something2""

This works:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

URL="http://www.google.com"

echo $(date) 'Running wget...'
wget "${URL}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use that code in IPython (colab):

```py
URL = 'http:://www.myurl.com'
!wget {URL}
```

I wrote this answer because was searching it!)

Answer (score 0):

Another handy option in Bash (or other shells) is to create a simple helper function that calls `wget` with the common options required by nearly all sites and any specific options you generally use. This reduces the typing involved and can also be useful in your scripts. I place the following in my ~/.bashrc to make it available to all shells/subshells. It validates input, checks that `wget` is available, and then passes all command line arguments to `wget` with the default options set in the script:

```
wgnc () {
    if [ -z $1 ]; then
        printf "  usage:  wg <filename>\t\t(runs wget --no-check-certificate --progress=bar)\n"
    elif ! type wget &>/dev/null; then
        printf "  error: 'wget' not found on system\n"
    else
        printf "  wget --no-check-certificate --progress=bar %s\n" "$@"
        wget --no-check-certificate --progress=bar "$@"
    fi
}
```

You can cut down typing even more by aliasing the function further. I use:

```
alias wg='wgnc'
```

Which reduces the normal `wget --no-check-certificate --progress=bar URL` to simply `wg URL`. Obviously, you can set the options to suit your needs, but this is a further way to utilize `wget` in your scripts.